# Email verification not working with deployed django app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, smtp

I've deployed a django website with Heroku. When a user creates an account in the app, a validation email is supposed to be sent. Do do that, I'm using smtp from gmail, and in my account settings, I've activated "less secure app access".
This works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when using the deployed app, I can't get the email to be sent.
The first time, I got a security warning from google saying someone connected to my account. I said it was me and tried again. I didn't get any other security warning but it seems the app is still unable to send emails.

Please, let me know if you have any idea what the issue might be.

Thanks.

Comment: I _very strongly_ urge you not to use Gmail for this. It isn't meant for programmatic use. SendGrid, Mailgun, Amazon SES, .. there are plenty of vastly better options.

Comment: Gmail doesn't work on linux server unless you have browser and logged in account on server.